# Arguments changing value in C

Tags: c, parameters, arguments

I have a problem with the arguments provided to a function changing value:

```
scene->shader->start( scene->shader->dataStart );
printf("%d\n",(int)scene->shader->dataStart);
```

Then, inside scene->shader->start, I print it out:

```
printf("%d\n",(int) _data );
```

It outputs the memory address from where I call scene->shader->start, then 0 when inside said function. Has it got something to do with the fact that I am calling the function by it's pointer from inside a struct? It makes absolutely no sense because the printf() from the function is the FIRST line of that function so I am definitely not setting it to 0 anywhere! Help is appreciated greatly, Erkling.

EDIT:

```
void shader1_setdown(void *);

typedef struct {
    GLuint shaderProgram;
    void *dataStart;
    void *dataEnd;
    void (*start)(void *data);
    void (*end)(void *data);
} renderShader;
```

The "scene" structure has a renderShader* in it.

Comment: Can you show some function signatures and variable declarations?

Comment: Yes, one second. I shall edit my post.

Comment: is scene->shader->dataStart declared on the stack?

Comment: If you're printing a pointer, using `%p` is better than using `%d` and casting.

Comment: I just discovered that in the function where I was setting scene->shader->start and scene->shader->end I had mixed up the two functions and this was causing the error. Thank you all for helping to the best of your abilities.

Answer (score 2):

You might be invading the implementation namespace by using identifiers starting with an underscore. This can lead to **undefined behavior** according to the C Language Standard.
Especially `_begin`, `_end`, `_data`, `_bss`, `_text` are used by some implementations to address certain segments of memory.

Change your identifiers to not start with an underscore.

Another posibility: You cannot printf an address with %d as an int. Especially if your pointer type is wider than your `int`. This would explain why you see zero for the `int`.
Suppose pointers are 64 bit big-endian, and ints are 32bit. You see the top 32 bit of the pointer, likely all zeros, interpreted as an int.

The standardly correct way to printf addresses is (cast **required** for non-void-ptrs):

```
printf ("%p\n", (void *)ptr);
```

Comment: I originally had used _data, but I changed it to another name ( blurp, which I am sure is unused, haha ), "blurp," and the same thing occurs.

Comment: @Erkling Did you do a `printf("%p\n", scene->shader->dataStart);`  _right_ before the line that does `scene->shader->start( scene->shader->dataStart );` ?

Comment: Yes, I changed that to check before the function call just to be sure.

Comment: I +1 because you gave some valuable information, but the problem was solved due to a mix up in the function signatures.